# Как обратиться к переменной из другого скрипта и из другой сцены, в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как обратиться к переменной из другого скрипта и из другой сцены? Например в настройках игры я ставлю управление мышкой( переменная будет выглядеть так: bool mouseControl = true) И что бы на уровне было управление мышкой, мне нужно чекнуть ту переменную mouseControl, а она в другом скрипте и сцене.

Comment: есть PlayerPrefs, он сохраняет данные на диск, те они будут доступны не только между уровнями но и между запусками

Comment: Прикол в том что там нет SetBool. только SetInt,Float,String

Comment: @SanRembak можно и через SetInt: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-do-you-save-a-boolean-to-playerprefs.5522/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализуйте Static Holder для вашего поля:

```
public static class StaticHolder 
{
   public static bool MouseControl { get; set; }
}
```

Приаттачьте его к вашей MainScene и обращайтесь как обычно в .NET

Comment: Тогда к вам ещё вопрос, как его можно будет сохранить что бы при запуске сцены опять не клацать на Toggle?

Comment: Так смысл паттерна StaticHolder именно в том, что он независим от окон/страниц/сцен. Ваш static-класс работает сам по себе.